# How to compile text as a function using AST?

Tags: python, exec, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to compile an input string (from a database) as a function and run it. This is the method I currently use:

Say I already have this function defined:

```
def foo():
    print "Yo foo! I am a function!"
```

And the string I read in from the database says I should call this function:

```
string_from_db = "foo()"
```

I then form a function (whose name I can control) which returns the function I read in from the database:

```
my_func_string = "def doTheFunc():\n\t return " + string_from_db
```

Now I compile the string, and set it to a function name I use later for processing:

```
exec my_func_string
processor = doTheFunc
```

I can call it later by running `processor()` which exclaims: `Yo foo! I am a function!`

**My Question:** Above this piece of code there is a comment (left by a long lost developer):

```
    ###############################################################
    # The following method for getting a function out of the text #
    # in the database could potentially be replaced by using      #
    # Python's ast module to obtain an abstract syntax tree and   #
    # put it inside of a function node                            #
    ###############################################################
```

I'd like to know more about this "potential replacement." I have taken a look at AST, but I am very confused on how it can help me do what I am already doing with the code above.

1. How can I accomplish the same thing using AST? Or where can AST help me in this process?
2. Is the implementation using AST better, and why?

Comment: Ye be in the realms of dark magic.

Comment: If you know the strings to be safe, there's no reason to use `ast` over `exec()`. The Python interpreter already implements parsing Python source code into function objects, why replicate it?

Comment: @millimoose I ended up going with the `exec` implementation, as I know my strings are safe. However, this question has enlightened me on better uses for `ast`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AST is a much safer choice when evaluating untrusted code, that could contain malicious instructions, `eval` or `exec` can execute any expression, while AST on the other hand, allows you to parse and validate the expression yourself, or execute a limited expression using `ast.literal_eval`, sort of like a sandbox, which allows only strings, lists, numbers and a few other things. This is just a simple example:

```
import ast
a = ast.literal_eval("[1,2,3,4]") //evaluate an expression safely.
```

Another example that parses a string into an AST:

```
import ast
source = '2 + 2'
node = ast.parse(source, mode='eval')
ast.dump(node)
```

This prints:

```
Expression(body=BinOp(left=Num(n=2), op=Add(), right=Num(n=2)))
```

There's a very good tutorial [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/11/28/python-internals-working-with-python-asts/) and also the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html)

Comment: Great tutorial! How would I go about "validating an expression for myself"? How can I tell if code is bad, or doesn't meet my requirements? Assuming I am going to need to compile small functions; I cannot limit myself to simple strings, lists, etc.

Comment: @babydanks you can find out if it calls any functions that it shouldn't, like `open` maybe.

Comment: Ah! At what level is this easiest to do? Once you have an ast function node? (ie. what would be the easiest way to check for `open`?)

Comment: @babydanks there's a `NodeVisitor` class that you should probably have a look at, there's an example in the tutorial too.

Comment: @babydanks the point is, that it gives you more control over what gets executed and what not, than `eval` or `exec` if you need it.